# iOS - Uniform style throughout App with stylesheet

Tags: ios, styles, stylesheet

I'm currently writing an iPhone app and I'd like to have a uniform style throughout the whole app (mostly uniform colors on multiple views).

Of course I can just remember the color and set it in every single view in the interface builder, but I'd prefer to have some kind of stylesheet file. This file would only contain `static const` properties. Every view would import the stylesheet and set it's properties via code.

Is there any more iOS/Objective-C way of achieving this?

In my opinion the optimal case would be a stylesheet, whose properties are settable through the interface builder. The interface builder should also know about this file and reflect made changes.

Comment: You can use the `UIAppearance` protocol to apply styles to your UI elements in a *similar* fashion to stylesheets. To see the effects in Interface Builder, though, you'd need to use IBDesignable features ... but the "dynamic" style changes would not be straightforward.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you the comment. If you like to post this as an answer (maybe with some resources). I'd be happy to accept it.